# CSS and interior columns

Tags: html, css

I have this CSS StyleSheet.

```
.visitscroll  {float:left;  width:750px; }
.visitscroll .interiorleft {width: 375px;  float: left;}
.visitscroll .interiorright {width: 375px; float: left; }
.visitscroll .fullwidth {float:left; width:750px; }
```

The left Column and right column and aligned properly, but I want to make a div below the the left and right column that is the full width. When I put something into the fullwidth div, it turns the page into one column.

So what I want is this:

```
A     |   B
      C
```

What I am getting is this:

```
A
B
C
```

I have confirmed that my div closing tags are correct, and am stuck on trying to figure this out.

All help is graciously appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want an element to:

**not bubble up beside a floated element**

Set `clear: left`, `clear: right` or `clear: both` depending on which floats you want to ignore.

**span the width of its container**

Set `float: none`

Answer (score 0):

You are not clearing the floats, you can do so by saying `clear:both;` or using `overflow:hidden;` on parent containing div

http://jsfiddle.net/x26Mw/